# Creating a List of UnityActions And Assigning Them to Buttons

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working on a tycoon game and I want to have several options on each building the player might click on. A shop should have an Eat, Invest, and Buy-off option while an office should have something like Work, Talk to Manager, etc. To do this I created one panel for the options and spawn in the number of options per building from a list of strings which instantiates a button for each string and assigns the button text to that particular string as such:

```
public override void Interact()
{
    Debug.Log(type);
    SetUpFunctions(activites);
}

public void SetUpFunctions(List<string> activs)
{
    foreach (string item in activs)
    {
        optionsUI.AddOption(item);
    }
}
```

The list of activities is assigned in the inspector. This method works perfectly and assigns each activity string to the button text. However, all the buttons created all have the same function assigned to them, so I decided to do the same thing with a list of methods and assign them to each button as I did with the strings:

```
[HideInInspector]public List<UnityAction> functions; //list of functions tied to each activity


public override void Interact()
{
    Debug.Log(type);
    functions.Add(Eat);
    functions.Add(Work);
    functions.Add(StopWork);
    SetUpFunctions(activites, functions);
}

public void SetUpFunctions(List<string> activs, List<UnityAction> funcs)
{
    //foreach (string item in activs)
    //{
    //    optionsUI.AddOption(item);
    //}
    var col = activs.Zip(funcs, (x, y) => new { X = x, Y = y });//combine the two lists as one
    foreach (var entry in col)
    {
        optionsUI.AddOption(col.X, col.Y);//Assign the activity name and function
    }

}

 public void Eat() 
{
    Debug.Log("Player is eating");
} 
public void Work() 
{
    Debug.Log("Player is Working");
} 
public void StopWork() 
{
    Debug.Log("Player Stopped Working");
}



 //From the OptionsUI script
 public void AddOption(string optionName, UnityAction optionFunc)
{
    OptionUIItem emptyOption = Instantiate(itemProfile, scrollViewContent);
    emptyOption.transform.SetParent(scrollViewContent);
    emptyOption.SetupOption(optionName, optionFunc);
}


//The script assigned to each button created
public class OptionUIItem : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text text;
    public Button btn;

    public void SetupOption(string name, UnityAction func)
    {
        text.text = name;
        btn.onClick.AddListener(func);
    }

    public void OnOptionSelect()
    {
        Debug.Log("Option selected");
    }
}
```

However, when I try doing it this way I get a NullReferenceException on the first function.Add(Eat);

My question is

1. Is it possible or even right to do it this way?
2. If so how do I resolve this in order to assign each function on the list to each button created and
3. any other methods that might be better to get this done like maybe using a dictionary?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you hide a field in the Inspector it is **not** automatically **initialized** (only serialized fields are), thus the `NullReferenceException` when trying to `Add` something to it.

You should be sure to do this already together with the declaration

```
public List<UnityAction> functions = new List<UnityAction>();
```